# Split SQL file with multiple databases in it

Tags: text-processing, files, sql

I've recently received a SQL-dump file, but it contains multiple databases in it. Is there any tool I can use to easily split this up into multiple .sql files, one per database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that this is a plaintext `.sql` file with `CREATE SCHEMA` or `CREATE DATABASE` statements, you can effectively do this with `split`:

```
$ split -p 'CREATE DATABASE' bigfile.sql splitsql_
```

This will create a set of new files, e. g. `splitsql_aa`, `splitsql_ab`, and so forth, wherein each file will start with the found `CREATE` statements.

From `split`'s manual:

> ```
> NAME
>      split -- split a file into pieces
> [...]
>      -p pattern
>              The file is split whenever an input line matches pattern,
>              which is interpreted as an extended regular expression.
>              The matching line will be the first line of the next
>              output file.  This option is incompatible with the -b and
>              -l options.
> ```

Comment: I'm getting an error stating invalid statement (P).

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't actually parse SQL — so it could be fooled by a CREATE DATABASE hidden in a text field somewhere. Might help to put a ^ in front of it...

Comment: Still no luck. It contains 3 databases: on localhost I can't import it correctly without the MySQL server freezing.

Comment: Is it actually _freezing_ or is it simply _taking a long time to parse a very large file_?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful, if you can still create the original DB dump, to separate the schema dump (i. e. the tables and other underlying structures) from the data dump (i. e. a metric tonne of `INSERT` statements).